# Flutter SVG only rendering after Hot Restart

Tags: svg, flutter

I am having trouble in rendering svg file using flutter_svg:^0.15.0. Some of the svgs render at the very first time but some do not.**When I hot restart the application it works fine.** I tried to downgrade the flutter_svg version but it didn't work.
I am having this trouble from weeks, I tried to svg cleaner because flutter_svg doesnot support for  attribute, but got nothing.

Console Output:
`I/flutter (12326): ══╡ EXCEPTION CAUGHT BY SVG ╞═══════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════
I/flutter (12326): The following assertion was thrown resolving a single-frame picture stream:
I/flutter (12326): Unable to load asset: images/weo-device NotConnecteds.svg
I/flutter (12326): 
I/flutter (12326): When the exception was thrown, this was the stack:
I/flutter (12326): #0      PlatformAssetBundle.load (package:flutter/src/services/asset_bundle.dart:221:7)
I/flutter (12326): <asynchronous suspension>
I/flutter (12326): #1      AssetBundle.loadString (package:flutter/src/services/asset_bundle.dart:67:33)
I/flutter (12326): #2      CachingAssetBundle.loadString.<anonymous closure> (package:flutter/src/services/asset_bundle.dart:162:56)
I/flutter (12326): #3      _LinkedHashMapMixin.putIfAbsent (dart:collection-patch/compact_hash.dart:293:23)
I/flutter (12326): #4      CachingAssetBundle.loadString (package:flutter/src/services/asset_bundle.dart:162:27)
I/flutter (12326): #5      AssetBundlePictureProvider._loadAsync (package:flutter_svg/src/picture_provider.dart:448:42)
I/flutter (12326): #6      AssetBundlePictureProvider.load (package:flutter_svg/src/picture_provider.dart:434:43)
I/flutter (12326): #7      PictureProvider.resolve.<anonymous closure>.<anonymous closure> (package:flutter_svg/src/picture_provider.dart:326:17)
I/flutter (12326): #8      PictureCache.putIfAbsent (package:flutter_svg/src/picture_cache.dart:67:22)
I/flutter (12326): #9      PictureProvider.resolve.<anonymous closure> (package:flutter_svg/src/picture_provider.dart:324:16)
I/flutter (12326): #10     SynchronousFuture.then (package:flutter/src/foundation/synchronous_future.dart:38:29)
I/flutter (12326): #11     PictureProvider.resolve (package:flutter_svg/src/picture_provider.dart:321:24)
I/flutter (12326): #12     _SvgPictureState._resolveImage (package:flutter_svg/svg.dart:641:10)
I/flutter (12326): #13     _SvgPictureState.didUpdateWidget (package:flutter_svg/svg.dart:629:7)
I/flutter (12326): #14     StatefulElement.update (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:4396:58)
I/flutter (12326): #15     Element.updateChild (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:2977:15)
I/flutter (12326): #16     SingleChildRenderObjectElement.update (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:5452:14)
I/flutter (12326): #17     Element.updateChild (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:2977:15)
I/flutter (12326): #18     RenderObjectElement.updateChildren (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:5161:32)
I/flutter (12326): #19     MultiChildRenderObjectElement.update (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:5561:17)
I/flutter (12326): #20     Element.updateChild (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:2977:15)
I/flutter (12326): #21     SingleChildRenderObjectElement.update (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:5452:14)
I/flutter (12326): #22     Element.updateChild (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:2977:15)
I/flutter (12326): #23     SingleChildRenderObjectElement.update (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:5452:14)
I/flutter (12326): #24     Element.updateChild (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:2977:15)
I/flutter (12326): #25     ComponentElement.performRebuild (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:4243:16)
I/flutter (12326): #26     Element.rebuild (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:3947:5)
I/flutter (12326): #27     StatelessElement.update (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:4298:5)
I/flutter (12326): #28     Element.updateChild (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:2977:15)
I/flutter (12326): #29     SingleChildRenderObjectElement.update (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:5452:14)
I/flutter (12326): #30     Element.updateChild (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:2977:15)
I/flutter (12326): #31     SingleChildRenderObjectElement.update (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:5452:14)
I/flutter (12326): #32     Element.updateChild (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:2977:15)
I/flutter (12326): #33     ComponentElement.performRebuild (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:4243:16)
I/flutter (12326): #34     Element.rebuild (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:3947:5)
I/flutter (12326): #35     StatelessElement.update (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:4298:5)
I/flutter (12326): #36     Element.updateChild (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:2977:15)
I/flutter (12326): #37     ComponentElement.performRebuild (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:4243:16)
I/flutter (12326): #38     Element.rebuild (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:3947:5)
I/flutter (12326): #39     ProxyElement.update (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:4557:5)
I/flutter (12326): #40     Element.updateChild (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:2977:15)
I/flutter (12326): #41     ComponentElement.performRebuild (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:4243:16)
I/flutter (12326): #42     Element.rebuild (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:3947:5)
I/flutter (12326): #43     StatefulElement.update (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:4413:5)
I/flutter (12326): #44     Element.updateChild (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:2977:15)
I/flutter (12326): #45     ComponentElement.performRebuild (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:4243:16)
I/flutter (12326): #46     Element.rebuild (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:3947:5)
I/flutter (12326): #47     StatelessElement.update (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:4298:5)
I/flutter (12326): #48     Element.updateChild (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:2977:15)
I/flutter (12326): #49     SliverMultiBoxAdaptorElement.updateChild (package:flutter/src/widgets/sliver.dart:1288:36)
I/flutter (12326): #50     SliverMultiBoxAdaptorElement.performRebuild.processElement (package:flutter/src/widgets/sliver.dart:1220:34)
I/flutter (12326): #51     Iterable.forEach (dart:core/iterable.dart:279:30)
I/flutter (12326): #52     SliverMultiBoxAdaptorElement.performRebuild (package:flutter/src/widgets/sliver.dart:1246:24)
I/flutter (12326): #53     SliverMultiBoxAdaptorElement.update (package:flutter/src/widgets/sliver.dart:1191:7)
I/flutter (12326): #54     Element.updateChild (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:2977:15)
I/flutter (12326): #55     ComponentElement.performRebuild (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:4243:16)
I/flutter (12326): #56     Element.rebuild (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:3947:5)
I/flutter (12326): #57     BuildOwner.buildScope (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:2432:33)
I/flutter (12326): #58     WidgetsBinding.drawFrame (package:flutter/src/widgets/binding.dart:773:20)
I/flutter (12326): #59     RendererBinding._handlePersistentFrameCallback (package:flutter/src/rendering/binding.dart:283:5)
I/flutter (12326): #60     SchedulerBinding._invokeFrameCallback (package:flutter/src/scheduler/binding.dart:1102:15)
I/flutter (12326): #61     SchedulerBinding.handleDrawFrame (package:flutter/src/scheduler/binding.dart:1041:9)
I/flutter (12326): #62     SchedulerBinding._handleDrawFrame (package:flutter/src/scheduler/binding.dart:957:5)
I/flutter (12326): #66     _invoke (dart:ui/hooks.dart:259:10)
I/flutter (12326): #67     _drawFrame (dart:ui/hooks.dart:217:3)
I/flutter (12326): (elided 3 frames from package dart:async)
I/flutter (12326): 
I/flutter (12326): Picture provider: ExactAssetPicture(name: "images/weo-device NotConnecteds.svg", bundle: null,
I/flutter (12326):   colorFilter: null)
I/flutter (12326): Picture key: AssetBundlePictureKey(bundle: PlatformAssetBundle#99193(), name: "images/weo-device
I/flutter (12326):   NotConnecteds.svg", colorFilter: null)`

My pubspec.yaml:

```
dev_dependencies:
  flutter_test:
    sdk: flutter
flutter:
  uses-material-design: true
  assets:
    - images/All Acs.svg
    - images/weo.svg
    - images/All Fans.svg
    - images/All Lights.svg
    - images/coffee.svg
    - images/lock.svg
    - images/morning.svg
    - images/Night.svg
    - images/too_hot.svg
    - images/forgot-password.svg
    - images/Accounts.svg
    - images/Favourites.svg
    - images/Room.svg
    - images/offnotification.svg
    - images/onnotification.svg
    - images/power.svg
    - images/power-chill.svg
    - images/sleep.svg
    - images/swing.svg
    - images/economy.svg
    - images/energy-saver.svg
    - images/cove.svg
    - images/loo.svg
    - images/arrow-down.svg
    - images/arrow-up.svg
    - images/curtains.svg
    - images/show password.svg
    - images/too_cold.svg
    - images/regulator.svg
    - Weo Status.svg
    - Wifi – Off.svg
    - Wifi – On.svg
    - logs.svg
    - home.svg
    - rooms.svg
    - Swing H.svg
    - Swing V.svg
    - ModeFan.svg
    - Humidity.svg
    - Dry.svg
    - AI.svg
    - GeneralModeAC.svg
    - theme_on.svg
    - theme_off.svg
    - weo-device NotConnected.svg
    - weo-offline.svg
    - Dot.svg
    - Switchboard.svg
    - WMS.svg
    - WMS-Sketch.svg
```

I have also tried putting just `image/` folder in assets.

I cannot build and publish my app due to this issue.
Please help me!

Update:
My Code Snippet:

```
Center(
  child: SvgPicture.asset(
    "images/$image",
    width: 55.0,
    height: 55.0,
  )
),
```

the image variable stores the name of svg.

Flutter Doctor:

```
Doctor summary (to see all details, run flutter doctor -v):
[√] Flutter (Channel stable, v1.12.13+hotfix.5, on Microsoft Windows [Version 10.0.17763.914], locale en-US)

[√] Android toolchain - develop for Android devices (Android SDK version 28.0.3)
[√] Android Studio (version 3.5)
[√] VS Code (version 1.41.1)
[!] Connected device
    ! No devices available

! Doctor found issues in 1 category.
```

I have changed the channel to master, that's when the problem started and when I got back to channel stable it persists.

PS:- All the svgs were working just fine a month ago. I haven't changed any of them.

Comment: How are you passing these images in your class?

Comment: What version of Flutter are you using?

Comment: I have updated the question, is anything else you want? please.

Comment: When you say restart, are you doing a hot-restart? What only works with a restart, displaying the SVGs? What happens what the images don't load, do you get an error?

Comment: When I run the application the svg doesn't render and the error is mentioned above, after that when I hot restart the application the svg gets render and I get no error.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, I found the solution to this. I removed all the spaces in the names of the SVGs, and after that, they all worked just fine. I don't know if that might be the cause of the issue but it did solve it.

Answer (score 0):

I have tried using SVG for displaying images several months back. What I can note is that, there are certain codes in SVG files that flutter_svg package does not know how to interpret yet. Which causes some SVG files to break/have issues to render at times; so there's not really much we can do, but to only use very simple SVG files.

Hence, I've asked my designer to produce simple SVG files instead, like not having gradient, or shadows, etc.

However, there are possible workarounds sometimes; but may not apply to all svg files. Using this tool https://github.com/RazrFalcon/svgcleaner/releases.

What you might want to try is download this tool, and clean your svg files, and use the cleaned svg files that this tool produces instead.

**What does this tool do?**

I'm not 100% sure, but it minifies, and changes the code of the SVG such that styles/classes are placed in-line, which increases the chance of your SVG file working the flutter_svg package.

Comment: Note that you might have to restart, or maybe re-install your app after changing the svg files that you use in your app with the cleaned svg files via the tool I linked

Comment: Actually i use that tool already, my bad I didn't mention that the svgs were working perfectly until last month. And now they are just broke.

Comment: Unfortunate. If you didn't update the package version, things shouldn't break when nothing's changed. Maybe try processing your svg files with cleansvg again just to double check things.

Comment: Also, I highly suggest that you try this on a real device too and see if it has the same behavior. I've actually had this rendering problem before to be honest. But I just ended up not relying on svg files due to the fact the svg rendering in flutter is not yet very reliable. In the case that these has become a very bad roadblock for you, maybe you might want to try using png files, but you're gonna spend a bit more time checking how it looks on varying device sizes

Comment: I have tried it on 4 different devices, 1) Realme 3 pro 2) Nexus 3)Pocco 4) Samsung A5. They all have this same issue. Well the issue started after 0.12.0 version of flutter_svg. One thing I can try is, try downgrading flutter and pinning flutter_svg to 0.12.0 but that flutter version doesn't generate 64 bit arch appbundle.